# Return data from Python's Redshift procedure call

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

`redshift_connector` is defined to be aligned with https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#id24 but I can't, after calling procedure, retrieve data into a dataframe.

Instead I'm getting `'mycursor'` value. How to overcome this?

`fetch*()` methods don't allow passing argument that will allow getting into data in `mycursor`.

I also tried [RECORDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-structure.html#r_PLpgSQL-record-type) type but no luck.

**Procedure's body**:

```
--CREATE TABLE reporting.tbl(a int, b int);
--INSERT INTO reporting.tblVALUES(1, 4);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE reporting.procedure(param IN integer, rs_out INOUT refcursor)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

BEGIN
  OPEN rs_out FOR SELECT a FROM reporting.tbl;
END;
$$;
```

**Python code**:

```
import redshift_connector

conn = redshift_connector.connect(
     host='xyz.xyz.region.redshift.amazonaws.com',
     database='db',
     port=5439,
     user="user",
     password='p@@s'
)
  

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("BEGIN;") 
res = cursor.callproc("reporting.procedure", parameters=[1, 'mycursor'])
res = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("COMMIT;")

#returns (['mycursor'],)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to define 2 cursors and only one is allowed.  "conn.cursor()" creates a cursor with name defined by redshift_connector.  "OPEN rs_out FOR SELECT a FROM reporting.tbl;" in your procedure opens a second cursor with the name mycursor.  The "cursor.fetchall()" is trying to fetch from the first cursor (and possibly erroring).  No command is fetching from mycursor.

I don't believe there is a way to get "cursor.fetchall()" to point to a different cursor name so I think you need to run the SQL commands (CALL, FETCH, etc) directly.

Something like this:

```
import redshift_connector

conn = redshift_connector.connect(
     host='xyz.xyz.region.redshift.amazonaws.com',
     database='db',
     port=5439,
     user="user",
     password='p@@s'
)

conn.run("BEGIN;") 
res = conn.run("CALL reporting.procedure(1, 'mycursor')")
res = conn.run("FETCH ALL FROM mycursor;")
conn.run("COMMIT;")

print(res)
```

Be aware that if you are on a single node Redshift cluster FETCH ALL isn't allowed and you will need to use FETCH FORWARD  instead.

Above untested and off the cuff.

Comment: Overall goal is to obtain the result from the procedure 'on the fly and move it into a dataFrame. Have you used `RECORDS` to address similar case?

Answer (score 0):

I modified Bill's solution by:

Adding context manager class:

```
import redshift_connector

class ConnectionError(Exception):
    pass

class CredentialsError(Exception):
    pass

class SQLError(Exception):
    pass

class RedshiftClientData():
    def __init__(self, config: dict) -> None:
        self.configuration = config

    def __enter__(self) -> 'cursor':
        try:
            self.conn = redshift_connector.connect(**self.configuration)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            return self.cursor

        except redshift_connector.InterfaceError as err:
            raise ConnectionError(err)

        except redshift_connector.ProgrammingError as err:
            raise CredentialsError(err)

        except Exception as ex:
            template = "An exception of type {0} occured in class RedshiftClient. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print(message)


    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace) -> None:
        self.conn.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()
        if exc_type is redshift_connector.ProgrammingError:
            raise SQLError(exc_value)
        elif exc_type:
            raise exc_type(exc_value)
```

Below tested and I confirm that data is fetched without any temp tables.

```
dbconfig = {
    "host": os.environ["redshift_host"],
    "database": os.environ["redshift_database"],
    "port": int(os.environ["redshift_port"]),
    "user": os.environ["redshift_username"],
    "password": os.environ["redshift_password"],
}

logging.info("Connecting to Redshift...")
with RedshiftClientData(dbconfig) as cursor:

    logging.info("Excel file prep...")

    #on the fly process
    cursor.execute("CALL reporting.procedure('mycursor');")
    cursor.execute("FETCH ALL FROM mycursor;")

    result = pd.DataFrame = cursor.fetch_dataframe()

    print(result)
```