# Capture Redshift's RAISE data from procedure's loop in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

At the beginning I prepared simple proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.record_example()
AS '
DECLARE
  rec RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM public.event
  LOOP
    RAISE INFO ''eventid = %'', rec.eventid;
  END LOOP;
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To not save result into temp table I want to catch it on the fly but can't find best approach to achieve it. Didn't find and good method in `redshift_connector` and `boto3`.

It seems that Redshift doesn't support [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html)

I could query `svl_stored_proc_messages` but I don't want any in-the-middle steps...

```
import redshift_connector

conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host='xyz-cluster.abc.region.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    database='',
    user='',
    password=''
 )

cursor = conn.cursor()
cur = cursor.execute("CALL public.record_example();")
```

Goal is to get `dataFrame` that would have data from `Messages`:

[image]

Comment: Can you RETURN the data instead of sending via RAISE INFO?

Comment: RETURN doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I suggest that you investigate why it "doesn't seem to work". This might help: [Return data from Python's Redshift procedure call - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75301104/174777)

Comment: I updated my solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75300605/return-data-from-pythons-redshift-procedure-call/75405772#75405772. Still, haven't get procedure with `RETURN` option working...

Comment: Ha! Didn't realise that was _also_ your question. :)